# @PostConstruct method called all the time on Jersey service

Tags: jersey, postconstruct

Hi I'm using GigaSpaces XAP which basically uses Spring and ApplicationContext to do all it's init and config etc... At some point in time during the loading of the web application a "cache" or what they call a space proxy is instantiated and is made available through the ServletContext. This space proxy is what allows you to write and read to and from the clustered cache.

So what I did initially was to get the space on each REST method. So...

```
@GET
public String myMethod()
{
space = (GigaSpace)context.getAttribute("mySpace");
space.write(new HelloWorld());
space.read(....);
etc...
return "Hello World!";
}
```

Since the space itself is thread safe I was instructed by the GigaSpaces guys to lookup the space once on init of my "application" so i can save on the lookup of the space.

So I looked into `@PostConstruct` where I did...

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
space = (GigaSpace)context.getAttribute("mySpace");
}
```

But it seems that this method is being called on every request I make! Does this mean my REST service is being created for each request I make? Is it because I'm using `@Scope("request")`?

If it Helps the servlet container is Jetty 7.1.4 and I'm using standard WAR to deploy.

Comment: if you have access to logs/console, throw a print in the bean constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But of course! System.out.println("Is your friend!")

And yes it is because of @Scope("request") changing to @Scope("singleton") causes the jersey "bean" to instantiate once instead of per request.